# Akka HTTP Routing DSL example is invalid

Tags: scala, server, akka, dsl, akka-http

So I'm trying to build a minimal HTTP server to receive POST requests but I can't get it done because somehow the examples on the [Akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html#routing-dsl-for-http-servers) are invalid and I can't get the `executionContext` from anywhere.

Here is my code:

```scala
object Main extends App {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("server-system")
  implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext  // can't resolve symbol executionContext

  // test route
  val route =
    path("test") {
      get {
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, "test"))
      }
    }

  val address = "localhost"
  val port = 8080
  val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt(address, port).bind(route)
  println(s"Server online at $address:$port\nPress RETURN to stop...")

  StdIn.readLine()
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind())                  // no implicits found for parameter
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())  // executor: ExecutorContext

}
```

I'm using version 10.2.1 which I'm importing with gradle like this:

```java
compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-http_2.12", version: "10.2.1"
compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-stream_2.12", version: "2.6.8"
```

Do you have any other quickstart example valid, or any other library which could be easier to use in order to setup a very minimal server like I'm trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to define [`ExecutionContext`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.html) in Scala. 2 of them for example are:

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
```

or:

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher
```

But before choosing which one you actually want to use, I suggest reading [What is execution context in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39939177/2359227)

You can also read [Dispatchers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html) by Akka for more customisable options. There is also the post [Execution Context and Dispatcher - Best practices, useful configurations and Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34117252/2359227).